# F-Test with P-value in Python

Tags: python, r, statistics

R allows us to compute F-test between two population:

```
> d1 = c(2.5579227634, 1.7774243136, 2.0025207896, 1.9518876366, 0.0, 4.1984191803, 5.6170403364, 0.0)
> d2 = c(16.93800333, 23.2837045311, 1.2674791828, 1.0889208427, 1.0447584137, 0.8971380534, 0.0, 0.0)
> var.test(d1,d2)

    F test to compare two variances

data:  d1 and d2
F = 0.0439, num df = 7, denom df = 7, p-value = 0.000523
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.008789447 0.219288957
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
        0.04390249
```

Note there it reports P-value also.

Another example, R gave this:

```
> x1 = c(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 68.7169110318)
> x2 = c(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1863361211)
> var.test(x1,x2)
#p-value = 1.223e-09
```

What's the equivalent in Python?
I checked this [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f.html), but doesn't seem to give what I want.

This code gives different P-value (especially example 2):

```
import statistics as stats
import scipy.stats as ss
def Ftest_pvalue(d1,d2):
    """docstring for Ftest_pvalue"""
    df1 = len(d1) - 1
    df2 = len(d2) - 1
    F = stats.variance(d1) / stats.variance(d2)
    single_tailed_pval = ss.f.cdf(F,df1,df2)
    double_tailed_pval = single_tailed_pval * 2
    return double_tailed_pval
```

Python gave this:

```
In [45]: d1 = [2.5579227634, 1.7774243136, 2.0025207896, 1.9518876366, 0.0, 4.1984191803, 5.6170403364, 0.0]
In [20]: d2 = [16.93800333, 23.2837045311, 1.2674791828, 1.0889208427, 1.0447584137, 0.8971380534, 0.0, 0.0]
In [64]: x1 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 68.7169110318]
In [65]: x2 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1863361211]

In [69]: Ftest_pvalue(d1,d2)
Out[69]: 0.00052297887612346176

In [70]: Ftest_pvalue(x1,x2)
Out[70]: 1.9999999987772916
```

Comment: The scipy p-value appears to be roughly half the R one (allowing for float representation and rounding issues). That would seem to imply a one-tailed vs two-tailed test.

Comment: @lvc's comment is exactly correct.  If you look at the documentation for `var.test`, the default alternative hypothesis is the two-sided test, and when you calculate the `cdf` as you're doing with Python, that's inherently a one-sided test.

Comment: @lvc: it doesn't seem so after I tried another example (see update)

Comment: @pdubois in that case you shouldn't multiply by 2, you should first subtract from 1 then multiply by 2.  2 - 1.9999999987772916 is 1.223e-09 after rounding.  The one-sided p-value of a statistic F is either `cdf(F)` or `1 - cdf(F)` depending on what side of the mean F lies.  You're trying to measure the probability of the statistic being "more extreme" than what's observed -- if F is on the left of the mean, "more extreme" means "further to the left", so `cdf(F)`.  If F is greater than the mean, then "more extreme" means "further to the right", so `1-cdf(F)`.

Comment: I don't know why this test does not exist in scipy, but one plausible reason (and a good alternative for you) is that people would prefer to do a [levene's test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.levene.html), which is considered more robust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/index.html) implementation:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
def Ftest_pvalue_rpy2(d1,d2):
    """docstring for Ftest_pvalue_rpy2"""
    rd1 = (robjects.FloatVector(d1))
    rd2 = (robjects.FloatVector(d2))
    rvtest = robjects.r['var.test']
    return rvtest(rd1,rd2)[2][0]
```

With this result:

```
In [4]: x1 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 68.7169110318]
In [5]: x2 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1863361211]
In [6]: Ftest_pvalue_rpy2(x1,x2)
Out[6]: 1.2227086010341282e-09
```

Answer (score 1):

I should mention that xalglib is a package full of statistical methods allowing to do this:
http://www.alglib.net/
http://www.alglib.net/hypothesistesting/variancetests.php
while it is less flexible than original methods based on scipy.

I should mention that correct double tailed calculation procedure can be found (in variancetests.c) as:

stat = ae_minreal(xvar/yvar, yvar/xvar, _state);
    *bothtails = 1-(fdistribution(df1, df2, 1/stat, _state)-fdistribution(df1, df2, stat, _state))

while what @Amit Kumar Gupta describes in his comment is false (if you merely double the difference between 1 and the one sided p-value, you can achieve values above 1)